# How to adjust layout for phones like Nexus 5 -- with soft navigation bar

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

Phones like Nexus 5 and HTC Desire have soft keys at the bottom for home, back, recent apps, etc.  With the Desire, you can use the arrow and get rid of the keys.  But the Nexus, unless you install a bunch of stuff, you are stuck with the keys.

I have layouts (sw330-dp) that look great on all phones, except the ones with the soft keys.  Sometimes, the black soft key bar at the bottom will cover the last little bit of my layout.

There seems to be no way to figure this out at runtime.  I have tried to do things like Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize) but that only seems to have to do with input mode -- like entering text.

How can I adjust layouts for phones with this soft navigation bar at the bottom?

Thanks

Comment: This is too generic a question to answer.  We have no idea what effect you're seeing due to the buttons, so we have no idea how to fix it.  But you have a bigger problem-  if you're assuming that sw330-dp is going to be a certain size, or even a certain ratio, you're wrong.  They won't be.  There will be a dozen different sizes.  If the presence of the bottom buttons screws up your layout, then your layout is broken on dozens of models.

Comment: As Gabe said, the problem you are facing will not be limited just to 2-3 mobiles. The effect will be wide ranged and so the layout you are using is not effective for all screen sizes. For such purpose I prefer to use [Percent Relative layout](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html&ved=0ahUKEwjSu9CU2aLSAhXEN48KHQl6D-wQFggZMAA&usg=AFQjCNHj6yjyO4ifgGvZTANz6SEi2rJBVQ). And pls pls pls, put the necessary code and snapshot of your problem!

Comment: I have lots of different phones of different sizes with the sw330-dp layout, and they all work fine.  Everything displays in the right place, sized perfectly.  The only time I have an issue is when there is a soft navigation bar that I can't get rid of.  I can't show the screenshot due to disclosure concerns, but the control at the bottom of the layout is a button.  On a couple of phones with the black soft navigation bar at the bottom, only the top half of the button shows.  The bottom of the button is covered by the navigation bar.  The rest of the layout is perfectly fine.

Comment: Don't see an editor to add code.  It's a Relative Layout.  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  Then a bunch of controls,using android:layout_below.  Truncated button at bottom sets a minHeight, and has android:layout_marginTop, left, and right of 10dp.

Comment: Just seems like when the navigation bar is on the screen (Nexus 5, HTC Desire, etc.) as opposed to below the screen (Samsung Galaxy, etc.) then Android thinks that the nav bar is part of the screen when it figures out layout sizes.  And there are some phones, like the HTC, where you can make the nav bar disappear.  Then the layout displays fine.

Comment: Maybe I should be making layout directories by height instead of width.If I do (i.e.) layout-h550dp and layout-h600dp instead of layout-sw330-dp, then Android can differentiate between the HTC Desire, LG V10 and Galaxy S7 and use different layouts for each. Using sw-330dp, all those phones fall into sw-330dp (they are actually all 360dp, but they fall into my 330dp since I don't have other designations until 600).  This may be the solution. I had read that since most apps scroll vertically, you tend to use width, not height. Is there a downside to using the height qualifiers instead of width?